# Where is the Mountain of the Father?

Tags: final-fantasy-dimensions

I couldn't find any online resources that say specifically where this is. So, I'm going to ask here: Where is the Mountain of the Father? The place where you obtain the summon Bahamut?

Answer (score 1):

In the Dark Gate, the room that links you to the 4 voids, a portal opens up at the north tip after you have entered Nil for the first time. This will take you there, and there you fight Bahamut.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find mountain of the father as you progress along with the story, it's almost impossible to miss as the game makes it a point to show to you that the portal to it has been opened.